# how to access physical memory in BSD platform from terminal or using any system call ?

Tags: freebsd, memory-usage, openbsd, virtual-memory, bsd

i just not know how to use mem command in BSD to access physical memory or virtual memory to get the ACPI tables and their Address .......

$mem Enter
mem command not found ....

so what can i do ?

is any body can give me clarification on this command how to use and what result it wil give and all....

please help me in this i am struggling from past three day on this ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `mem` command, not sure why you would think there is... You're probably looking for `kdbg` and it's `dump memory` command. In `kdbg` enter `help $cmd` (where $cmd is a command) for more help.

There is a `/dev/mem` special device that represents physical memory. You can read and write to this device, specifically you might be interested in using `dd` to copy chunks out.

Both of these require root access and both are easily capable of crashing or corrupting memory.
Be careful using them.

Comment: thank you ! boss i think i have to be clear on this topic ??

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

`sysctl hw.physmem`

Then there is also:

> su-3.2# grep memory /var/run/dmesg.boot
>
> usable memory = 8571846656 (8174 MB)
>
> avail memory  = 8270299136 (7887 MB)
>
> su-3.2#

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's completely not what he's asking for.

Comment: yes! answer is Completely not What i wanted !!!